# After migrating magento 1 to magento2 when try to reindex, i got an error

Tags: magento2

Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'created_in' used in key specification without a key length, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
>     `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
>     `name` text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
>     `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
>     `group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
>     `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
>     `website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
>     `confirmation` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
>     `created_in` text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
>     `dob` date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
>     `gender` int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
>     `taxvat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
>     `lock_expires` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
>     `shipping_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
>     `billing_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
>     `billing_firstname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
>     `billing_lastname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
>     `billing_telephone` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
>     `billing_postcode` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
>     `billing_country_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
>     `billing_region` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
>     `billing_street` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
>     `billing_city` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
>     `billing_fax` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
>     `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
>     `billing_company` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_IN` (`created_in`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_LOCK_EXPIRES` (`lock_expires`),
>     INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
>     FULLTEXT `FTI_76EE125693165A11F2D49A0116049156` (`name`, `email`, `taxvat`, `shipping_full`, `billing_full`, `billing_firstname`, `billing_lastname`, `billing_telephone`, `billing_postcode`, `billing_region`, `billing_city`, `billing_fax`, `billing_vat_id`, `billing_company`)
>   ) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Please see OMG Ponies' answer for the reason of this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length

To solve it, run this query before the first reindexing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `name` text COMMENT 'Name',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group_id',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created_at',
  `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website_id',
  `confirmation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation',
  `created_in` text COMMENT 'Created_in',
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Dob',
  `gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gender',
  `taxvat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat',
  `lock_expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires',
  `shipping_full` text COMMENT 'Shipping_full',
  `billing_full` text COMMENT 'Billing_full',
  `billing_firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname',
  `billing_lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname',
  `billing_telephone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone',
  `billing_postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode',
  `billing_country_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id',
  `billing_region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region',
  `billing_street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street',
  `billing_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city',
  `billing_fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax',
  `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id',
  `billing_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`,`email`,`created_in`,`taxvat`,`shipping_full`,`billing_full`,`billing_firstname`,`billing_lastname`,`billing_telephone`,`billing_postcode`,`billing_region`,`billing_city`,`billing_fax`,`billing_company`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='customer_grid_flat';
```

Let me know if this helps